# $M^{H^*}= M^{coH}$, $M^H=M^{coH^o}$ for a Hopf algebra $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Susan Montgomery gave the Lemma 1.7.2 without proof in her book 'Hopf algebras and their actions on rings' which states that $M^{H^*}= M^{coH}$ for a right $H$-comodule $M$ with left $H^*$-module structure and $M^H=M^{coH^o}$ for a left $H$-module $M$ with right $H^o$-comodule structure.

Here, $H$ is a Hopf algebra. $M^H=\{m \in M | h \cdot m= \epsilon(h)m, \forall h \in H \}$ and $M^{coH}=\{m\in M | \rho(m)= m \otimes 1\}$ are the sets of invariants and coinvariants respectively.

I'd like to complete the proof. My intuition said that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(m) = m\otimes 1 &\Leftrightarrow h^* \cdot m =<h^*,1>m\\
&\Leftrightarrow h^*\cdot m= \epsilon(h^*)m.
\end{aligned}
$$
But I am stuck at $<h^*,1>=\epsilon(h^*)$ and $\Leftarrow$ in the top row. By definition, $h^* \cdot m= \sum <h^*, m_{(1)}> m_{(0)}$, but how to show $\rho(m) = m\otimes 1$ from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez，Yes， anything wrong？

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question on my own. For the one hand,
$$
<h^*,1_H>=<h^*,u(1_k)>=<u^*(h^*),1_k>=u^*(h^*)=\epsilon_{H^*}(h^*).
$$
For the other hand, we can choose a basis $\{x_i\}$ for $M$ since $M$ is a vector space. Assume $\rho(m)= \sum m_i\otimes h_i$, $m=\sum a_jx_j$ and $m_i=\sum a_{ik}x_k$. Because $h^*\cdot m=<h^*,1_H>m$, the left $H^*$-module structure of right $H$-comodule states that

$$
\sum<h^*,h_i>m_i= <h^*,1_H>m,
$$
which means
$$
\sum<h^*,h_i> \sum a_{ik}x_k= <h^*,1_H> \sum a_jx_j.
$$
Consider the coefficient of $x_k$ for both sides, then
$$
\sum_i <h^*,a_{ik}h_i>= <h^*,a_k \cdot 1_H>.
$$
This means
$$
<h^*,a_k \cdot 1_H-\sum_i a_{ik}h_i>=0,\  \forall h^*\in H^*.
$$
Note that $<,>$ is nondegenerate, this means
$$
a_k \cdot 1_H-\sum_i a_{ik}h_i=0.
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(m) &= \sum a_{ik}x_k \otimes h_i\\
&=\sum_k x_k \otimes \sum_i a_{ik} h_i\\
&=\sum_k x_k \otimes a_k \cdot 1_H\\
&=\sum_k a_k x_k \otimes 1_H\\
&=m \otimes 1_H.
\end{aligned}
$$
I also have another proof to avoid considering the basis. Assume again $\rho(m)= \sum m_i\otimes h_i$ with $h_i$ linearly independent. Because
$$
\sum<h^*,h_i>m_i= <h^*,1_H>m, \forall h^*,
$$
Let $h^*=h_i^*$, then $m_i=<h_i^*,1_H>m$. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
<h^*,1_H>m &= \sum<h^*,h_i>m_i\\
&= \sum<h^*,h_i><h_i^*,1_H>m\\
&= <h^*,\sum<h_i^*,1_H>h_i>m, \forall h^*\in H^*.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum <h_i^*,1_H>h_i=1_H,
$$
which indicates
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(m) &=\sum m_i \otimes h_i\\
&= \sum <h_i^*,1_H>m \otimes h_i\\
&=m \otimes \sum <h_i^*,1_H>h_i\\
&=m \otimes 1_H.
\end{aligned}
$$

As to $M^H=M^{coH^o}$, one need to consider the right $H^o$-comodule structure of a left $H$-module which was introduced at Lemma 1.6.4 in Susan Montgomery's book i.e.
$$
\rho(m)=\sum m_i\otimes f_i,
$$
where $a\cdot m= \sum f_i(a)m_i$.